# SVN: how to check if a merge is a "fast forward" merge?

Tags: svn, merge

For some reasons, our team needs to use subversion instead of git. However, we still want to adopt a "feature branch workflow" to make the trunk as stable as possible. By "feature branch workflow" I mean all the new feature or bug fix need to be done in a branch, tested, then merge back to trunk.

We want the merging handled by our CI/CD pipeline automatically, so we need to check if the merge is a "fast forward" merge.

By "fast forward" merge I mean, if I want to merge `feature_branch_a` back to `trunk`. I need to first merge the newest updates from `trunk` to `feature_branch_a`, resolve the conflicts, test the code then merge `feature_branch_a` back to `trunk`. After the merge, the `trunk` should be identical to `feature_branch_a`.

I know this can be easily done in Git, but is there a way we can do this kind of check in Subversion?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, there should be no need to check if the merge is "fast forward" or not. In Subversion, you should always perform two merges in order to reintegrate a branch: first merge `trunk` to `feature_branch_a` and then merge `feature_branch_a` back to `trunk.`

Check the [Reintegrating a Branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.reintegrate) chapter in the [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/) for further details.

Comment: People may forget to first merge `trunk` to `feature_branch_a`, so I need the CI/CD pipeline to double check that.